# Delete a temporal file when it is closed in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a function similar to this:

```py
def open_tmp():
    tmp = mktemp()
    copy('file.txt', tmp)
    return open(tmp, 'rt')
```

And I would like to remove automatically the created temporal file when the file will close, for example:

```py
file = open_tmp()
# Do something with file
file.close()  # I want to remove the temporal file here
```

Is it possible? I thought to create a subclass of BaseIO and rewrite the close() function, but I think it is too much work because I would have to rewrite all the BaseIO methods.

Comment: I recommend not reinventing the wheel: use the built-in [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module. See the Examples that wraps it in a context manager.

Comment: Assuming you mean temporary rather than temporal and also that the mktemp() function is from the tempfile module, then please review https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html for a better solution. tempfile.mktemp() was deprecated since Python 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```py
import os
import tempfile

def open_tmp():
    tmp = tempfile.mkstemp()
    copy('file.txt', tmp)  # This copy the file.txt to tmp
    file = open(tmp, 'rt')
    old_close = file.close
    
    def close():
       old_close()
       os.remove(tmp)

    file.close = close
    return file
```

Comment: glad to know that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this code snippet. As per security concern I recommended to use tempfile instead of your code.**

```
import os
import tempfile

new_file, file_path = tempfile.mkstemp()

try:
    with os.fdopen(new_file, 'w') as temp_file:
        # Do something with file
        temp_file.write('write some dumy text in file')

finally:
    os.remove(file_path)
```

Comment: The problem is that my code is only an example of that actually I need. And I need to return the opened stream to a tempfile (whatever I create it) and when I close the file, then, actomatically, remove it. Outside of the function I'm not going to have the path to the temporal file.